# „Zusammen geführt“ oder „zusammengeführt“?

Tags: difference, verb, adverb, separable-verb

Ich bin in einem Artikel über diesen Satz gestoplert:

> Er hat Programm X mit Programm Y zusammen geführt.

Es ging darum, dass die Funktionen von beiden Programmen (Software) in einem Programm aufgingen.

Mich stört das Leerzeichen zwischen *zusammen* und *geführt*; ich würde *zusammengeführt* schreiben. *Zusammen geführt* klingt als wären es zwei unabhängige Dinge (hier Programme), die immer noch unabhängig sind, aber eben von der selben Person geführt werden.

Sind beide Schreibweisen hier korrekt? Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Die [amtlichen deutschen Rechtschreibregeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) behandeln zusammengesetzte Verben in den §§ 33 mit 35. Da es sich auf keinen Fall um eine untrennbare Zusammensetzung handelt (»Er führt zusammen« und nicht <strike>»Er zusammenführt«</strike>) und da der Verbstamm nicht *sein* ist, ist § 34 hier relevant.

> § 34: Partikeln, Adjektive, Substantive oder Verben können als Verbzusatz
>   mit Verben trennbare Zusammensetzungen bilden. Man schreibt sie
>   nur in den Infinitiven, den Partizipien sowie im Nebensatz bei Endstellung
>   des Verbs zusammen.

(Anmerkung: Hier geht es um trennbare, zusammengesetzte Verben wie *vornehmen* (»ich nehme mir etwas vor«). Das ergibt sich meines Erachtens nur aus den umgebenden Passagen zweifelsfrei, die ich hier nicht zitiere.)

> Dies betrifft
>
> 1. Zusammensetzungen mit einer Verbpartikel als erstem Bestandteil.
>      Verbpartikeln sind Bestandteile, die
>
>    1. formgleich mit Präpositionen sind, zum Beispiel:
>         *ab-, an-, auf-, aus-, […], zwischen-*
>    2. formgleich mit Adverbien, insbesondere Adverbien der Richtung, des Ortes, der Zeit sowie mit Pronominaladverbien sind, zum Beispiel:
>         *abwärts-, auseinander-, beisammen-, davon-, davor-, dazu-, dazwischen-, empor-, fort-, her-, heraus-, herbei-, herein-, hin-, hinaus-, hindurch-, hinein-, hintenüber-, hinterhre-, hinüber-, nebenher-, nieder-, rückwärts-, umher-, voran-, voraus-, vorbei-, vorher-, vorweg-, weg-, weiter-, wieder-, zurück-, **zusammen-,** zuvor-*
>
>    E1: Zur Unterscheidung von Verbpartikel und selbständigem Adverb: Bei Zusammensetzungen liegt der Hauptakzent normalerweise auf der Verbpartikel (vgl. *w**ie**dersehen, zus**a**mmensitzen*), während bei Wortgruppen das selbständige Adverb auch unbetont sein kann (vgl. *wieder s**e**hen, zusammen s**i**tzen*). Wenn das Betonungskriterium nicht zu einem eindeutigen Ergebnis führt, hilft in manchen Fällen eine der folgenden Proben weiter:
>
>    1. Das Adverb kann im Aussagesatz vor dem finiten Verb an erster Stelle
>         stehen, die Verbpartikel hingegen nicht, vgl.: *Dabei wollte sie nicht immer sitzen, sondern auch ab und zu mal stehen* (Adverb *dabei*), aber *Dabeisitzen wollte sie nicht immer* (Verbpartikel *dabei-*).
>    2. Zwischen Adverb und Infinitiv können ein oder mehrere Satzglieder eingeschoben werden, zwischen Verbpartikel und verbalen Bestandteil hingegen
>         nicht, vgl.: *Sie wollte dabei nicht immer sitzen, sondern auch ab und zu mal stehen* (Adverb *dabei*), aber *Sie wollte nicht immer dabeisitzen* (Verbpartikel *dabei-*).
>
> […]

(Anmerkung: Im Original minimal andere Nummerierung. Was ich als »1.« wiedergegeben habe, steht dort als (1) oder (1.1). Auf dieser Seite lässt es sich auf diese Art allerdings am übersichtlichsten darstellen.)

Der Betonungstest liefert bei mir in der vorhergesehenen Bedeutung:

> Er hat zwei Programme zu**sam**mengeführt.

Ein klarer Fall für Zusammenschreibung.

Die andere Betonung, »Er hat zwei Programme zusammen ge**führt**«, lässt mich erwarten, dass er – wie du vermutest – gleichzeitig zwei Programme geleitet hat.

Leider kommen falsche Getrenntschreibungen in meiner Beobachtung sehr häufig vor; deutlich häufiger als falsche Zusammenschreibungen. Ob daran die Rechtschreibreform, die Digitalisierung, die Schulbildung oder anderes schuld ist, möchte ich nicht beurteilen. Zu guter Letzt wäre diese Antwort unvollständig ohne Willy Brandt zu ziteren:

> Jetzt sind wir in einer Situation, in der wieder *zusammenwächst,* was *zusammengehört.*

Oder verkürzt:

> Jetzt wächst zusammen, was *zusammengehört.*

Answer (score 2):

Du hast völlig recht, und der Duden [bestätigt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammenfuehren) das.